# PLSQL saber a quantidade de registros dentro de um "for cursor"

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Dentro do exemplo abaixo :

```
Begin
  For r in (select * from tabela)
  Loop
    ..... ;
  End loop;
End;
```

Existe alguma forma direta de saber dentro do loop quantos registros tem o cursor ?

Comment: Creio não ser possível diretamente, face a "filosofia" do Cursor.

Answer (score 3):

Tente assim:

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() total_de_registros
                  ,t.*
              FROM tabela t)
  LOOP
    .. .. .;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

No exemplo acima, a clausula `COUNT(*) OVER()` conta todos os registros que retornam na query sem a necessidade de adicionar um `group by`.

Comment: Sim! Neste caso, utilizando query partition clause: http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions.php#query_partition_clause, você consegue agrupar valores em uma coluna sem afetar a query em si. No caso acima utilizei um count(*) com um OVER(), dentro do OVER() eu poderia ter uma clausula de agrupamento utilizando partition by, mas acim eu apenas contei todos os registros que retornam na query.

Comment: Entendi! Nos próximos irei explicar melhor!

Comment: ok, pode apagar

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se essa é a ideia.

Mas pode ser feito dessa maneira.

```
declare
vtabela tabela%rowtype;
Begin
  select t.* into vtabela from tabela;
  For r in 1..vtabela.count loop
  Loop
    ..... ;
  End loop;
End;
```

Comment: declare
vuser_tables user_tables%rowtype;
VN_ROWS NUMBER;
begin
  select X.* into vUSER_TABLES from USER_TABLES X;
  For r in 1..vUSER_TABLES0.count 
  loop
    VN_ROWS := VN_ROWS + R.NUM_ROWS;
  end loop;
End; deu erro nesta adaptação...

Comment: Fazendo desse jeito vai dar erro mesmo. O SELECT INTO dá erro se o número de resultados é diferente de 1. Teria que usar um BULK COLLECT INTO, com uma declaração totalmente diferente para vtabela (ex.: TABLE OF tabela%rowtype), mas aí estaria trazendo todos os resultados para dentro de uma coleção, o que não sei se seria desejado.